# Laravel 5.3 form redirects to login on post

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3

I've got a form that is supposed to go to **OrgController@store** on post to the page. What happens is it seems to redirect to / and never makes it into my store function in OrgController.

According to my networks tab in Firebug it POSTS to /org/add then makes a GET request to login for some reason, even if I comment out my call to the Auth Middleware.

That GET Request to login sees that I'm logged in and then redirects me to where the Laravel Auth RedirectIfAuthenticated is set to go. (Which in this case is /).

Basically I want my routing to respect auth but also POST to my form.

My Route Looks like this.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'org'], function () {
    Route::get('search', 'OrgController@search');
    Route::get('browse', 'OrgController@browse');
    Route::get('add', 'OrgController@add');
    Route::post('add', 'OrgController@store');
});
```

and my form looks like this.

```
 <form method="post" action="">
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="parent_org">Parent Organization</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="parent_org" required="true">
                        <option>Org Unit 1</option>
                        <option>Org Unit 2</option>
                        <option>Org Unit 3</option>
                        <option>Org Unit 4</option>
             </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
             <label for="org_name">Org Unit Name</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="org_name" required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox">Will users be added directly to this organization unit?</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Org</button>
 </form>
```

my **php artisan route:list** shows the following.

```
|        | GET|HEAD | org                    |       | App\Http\Controllers\OrgController@search                              | web,eventlog,auth  |
|        | POST     | org/add                |       | App\Http\Controllers\OrgController@store                               | web,eventlog,auth  |
|        | GET|HEAD | org/add                |       | App\Http\Controllers\OrgController@add                                 | web,eventlog,auth  |
|        | GET|HEAD | org/browse             |       | App\Http\Controllers\OrgController@browse                              | web,eventlog,auth  |
|        | GET|HEAD | org/search             |       | App\Http\Controllers\OrgController@search                              | web,eventlog,auth  |
```

I'm using the a custom Auth provider extending the Laravel built in Auth.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woops.

The issue was that I forgot I had put in my exception handler.

```
  if ($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
            return redirect('/login');
   }
```

As well I didn't have my CSRF token in my form. So it was suppressing the invalid CSRF token error and also redirecting to login.

.. lesson learned.

Answer (score 3):

A post route does not work correctly and takes you to login page. When you have a form with method="post" and the action is for a POST route. If the form doesn't have the security token, like:

```
<form action="xxx" method="post">
   ...
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
   ... 
</form>
```

What will happen is that the route will always redirect you to Login, because in order to keep your form safe, as it cannot find Laravel's token, it will request login.

Answer (score 2):

Don't disable the token in the login page or any url with post request for security purpose. Just add `{{csrf_token()}}` in your form fields. csrf_token returns an input hidden field with a token. it protects your forms from abuse attack outside.

```
 <form method="post" action="">
           <div class="form-group">
                <label for="parent_org">Parent Organization</label>
      Add csrf_token anywhere inside your form
             {{csrf_token()}}
                <select class="form-control" id="parent_org" required="true">
                            <option>Org Unit 1</option>
                            <option>Org Unit 2</option>
                            <option>Org Unit 3</option>
                            <option>Org Unit 4</option>
                 </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="org_name">Org Unit Name</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="org_name" required="true">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox">Will users be added directly to this organization unit?</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Org</button>
     </form>
```